# I am attempting to make a javascript that will summarize every number between 0-100 who's lattermost digit contains a user selected digit between 0-9

Tags: javascript, html, function, for-loop, indexof

As the title stated, I am trying to do a javascript in which the user enters a digit between 0-9. It will then summarize all of the numbers who's lattermost digit contains the user's digit, i.e. if the user selects 7 it summarizes 7, 17, 27, 37, 47, 57, 67, 77, 87, and 97. However, it just returns a 0. Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="write">
    <button id="knapp">Klicka på mig!</button>
    <div id="box"></div>
    
    <script>
    document.getElementById("knapp").addEventListener("click", funktion);
    
    var summa = 0;
    var summa2 = 0;

    function funktion(){
        
        let imported = document.getElementById("write").value;

        for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){

            summa = i;
        
            if((i+'').indexOf(imported)){

                i += summa2;

                document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = summa2;
            }
        }   
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `summa2` other than when you assign it 0?  And why do you modify the value of `i`  (when you do `i += summa2`) ?  You could debug this yourself by inspecting the values of `i` and `summa2` using console.log inside your loop...

Answer (score 1):

This can generally be summarized as:

```
const found = [];
let searchFor = '7';

for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    if((i+'').endsWith(searchFor)){
        found.push(i);
    }
}

console.log(found);
```

I think [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) is much easier to reason about than `indexOf`, which returns `-1` when not found, by the way.

Storing what's found in an array is also easier, and you can later get a delimited string back if you need.

**Edit**

Going back to the original one, maintaining variables inside and outside of a function generally isn't a good idea, and really isn't necessary, either, so I've removed `summa` and `summa2`.

Inside of the loop, you were setting one of these global variables to the current index, for a reason I don't know, so that was removed.

As noted, `indexOf` returns the position in a string that a substring was found. When you, for instance, test `'9'.indexOf('7')` you'll get `-1`, which is not found, however when tested for [truthiness in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), will get converted to true. So pretty much everything except what you are looking for is true. You could use `!` to then negate that, but that's just getting uglier.

After your test, you are adding `summa2` on to `i`, however `summa2` is never changed from the initial value of `0`.

Lastly, inside of your loop, you are constantly settings the value of a text box, 100 times, to the value of `summa2`, which as previously noted, is always `0`.

**Edit 2**

This code does not sum up numbers, it just gets the numbers and it is assumed that summing them should be pretty easy. It is unclear from the OP's sample data versus the words they use what exactly they are going for.

Comment: This answer could be improved if you commented on the errors the OP made (just a suggestion)

Comment: Okay @devlincarnate, I tried my best to comment on that!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to actually loop through every single number to determine if it ends with a specific number. If you take a range from 0 - 100, then all numbers ending with e.g. 7 will be 7, 17, 27 etc. The jump is by 10. When you start to increase the length of the user supplied number e.g. 27, then your jump becomes 100

```js
function numbersEndsWith(number, start, end) {
  const step = Math.pow(10, (number + "").length);
  for (let i = number + start; i < end; i += step) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

numbersEndsWith(7, 0, 100);
numbersEndsWith(7, 50, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `summa = i;` and change `i += summa2;`  to  `summa2 += i;`.
Place `document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = summa2;`
after `for` block. I didn't try, but should work.

I would do totally different way:
if you need to summarize 7, 17, 27, 37, 47, 57, 67, 77, 87, and 97
That is  `0+10+...+80+90 + 7*10`.
The first part is always `450`, the second part is your number multiplied by 10. This is one line function, you don't need for() loop.